# Controlling Image Size for Posts in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, image-size

I've been playing around with WordPress. As a programmer, the media library seems a little strange to me - but I'm keen to understand how I can achieve what I need with the framework. Cue WordPress enthusiasts...

I need to force my WordPress post images to be a certain size. I'm not talking about the thumbnail size, which I've found can be easily manipulated within the loop, but the images that actually get *inserted* into a post, amongst the writing and the other media. I have a fixed content width, and I would like the images to reflect that width (uncropped).

Obviously, I could run some sort of Regular Expression that could identify the image tags, and replace them with new sizes, but is there really no other way of forcing image sizes within the post while retaining there position amongst the formatted writing that comes with it?

So far, I'm guessing that there is a CSS property out there that is used by WordPress in all images. At a push, I'm willing to go with this - whatever it may be (answer needed). But I was hoping that their might be some more involved code (perhaps something I could plop into the functions.php file) which could actually force any *inserted* post images to be a certain width.

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If that's only about limiting the max width of an image and prevent an image from overflow, you could use the $content_width variable in your theme:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6499/how-to-create-a-conditional-content-width-for-a-wordpress-theme

Comment: This is partly helpful, but the issue here is that the user must select the 'large' image size in the media gallery, save the changes, and then click the 'insert into post' button. The added hassle of choosing the 'large' radio button, and then saving, defies the point of a quick uploading process for a client who may not always remember to do this. If you can give me a way of forcing the image size to 'large' on every upload then I'll give you the answer. I have to say, I'm very surprised that this isn't a more widely discussed issue.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's really possible without hacking the core JS files. There is a function called `add_image_size` that helps you define new sizes, but I am not aware of one forcing you do anything. You could also do another thing - adding a filter for `the_content` when you manually alter the image data with a regex as you mentioned at the beginning.